# Noun categorization

Tags: nouns

I want to store nouns in a database, but the categorization is not all that clear to me.
What I mean is that it seems that many words can be applied to different categories.

Categories identified:

- Common
- Proper
- Concrete
- Abstract
- Collective
- Countable / Uncountable (mass)

It would seem that the only clear distinctions are:

- Proper
- Concrete vs Abstract
- Countable vs Uncountable

It would seem that:

- Common nouns can be either concrete or abstract, countable or uncountable.
- Collective nouns can be common (and all other categories mentioned in previous point)

I'm a bit fuzzy on what the purpose of this categorisation, so could you confirm that this is correct?

Comment: What categories apply to a word depends on how it is used. A *key*, for example, could be concrete (e.g. car keys, a piano key, the Escape key) or abstract (e.g. "the key to success," an encryption key, the key of D♭ major). *Whiskey* could be uncountable (*Ireland exported 15 percent more whiskey this year than last*) or countable (*the menu offered six different whiskeys but only two vodkas*; *I ordered whiskeys for the table*). And as you surmise, the categorizations are not mutually exclusive and not always agreed upon.

Comment: Where do you see a nominalised adjective, or an eponym?

Comment: @Greybeard Are these suggestions for additional categories?

Comment: @html_programmer No. I was wondering about your opinion of them. Are they a category, or a subcategory? Choster has given a very good comment. The type of noun is really dependent upon the context: The importance of context cannot be overstated. Why are you classifying nouns?

Comment: @Greybeard My goal is to build a database of words and create an analysis bot that can make some conclusions by reading texts in an automated way. Not an easy task... language definitely not black and white. I will look deeper into these contexts and look for the best way to store words / data / contexts.

Comment: @html_programmer you may be interested in https://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/ an automated parser.

Comment: I would like to build and interpret my own, but thanks for the link.